# sharepoint rest query for multiple parameters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, rest, odata

I am using REST query for getting values in search

I am trying to use a filter that combines topic and field

```
 http://URL/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:http://URL/en/topic/article OR
 Path:http://URL/ne/topic/article (topic:Cricket) AND 
(FieldData:News) '&
rowlimit=5&selectproperties='Title, Author'&enablequeryrules=true
```

The problem here is that, it is bringing results that has Topic: Cricket and the ones with Field:News and ones with both

But what is want are the ones with both **Topic: Cricket AND Field:News**

I also tried

```
 http://URL/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:http://URL/en/topic/article OR
 Path:http://URL/ne/topic/article (topic:Cricket AND FieldData:News) '&
rowlimit=5&selectproperties='Title, Author'&enablequeryrules=true
```

Comment: Can you try this `'Path:http://URL/en/topic/article OR Path:http://URL/ne/topic/article AND (topic:Cricket AND FieldData:News)'`

Comment: ya tried it now
still not getting the desired result

Comment: That is strange

Comment: yeah. . not sure why the and is not being considered

Comment: try this '(Path:http://URL/en/topic/article OR
 Path:http://URL/ne/topic/article) AND( (topic:Cricket) AND ( FieldData:News) ) '